# Using VLC as Audio RTP Server

Tags: vlc-media-player, audio-streaming

I am trying to Stream Audio file from VLC with SDP file option.

At the Client VLC - it seems to listen the stream as there was no port unreachable ICMP messages in wireshark. But it does not seem to capture the audio file streamed from the server.

I am using the same sdp file in server and client. Is there anything need to be done at Client VLC for correct capturing?

For SDP File - the Source IP is correctly set to Server Side IP. and the file has both parameters for recv and send.

> Running on the server:
>
> $ vlc -vvv C:\Sample.wav --sout "#rtp{dst=192.168.0.61,port=8000,sdp=file://C:/test.sdp}"
>
> Runing on the client:
>
> $ vlc test.sdp